# draw to a single screen in cloning mode

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way in .Net (or other platforms) to draw to only one screen from a set of screens that are configured in Windows to clone the display (meaning all show the same display)?

Thanks...

Comment: you mean like screen-sharing?

Comment: If you setup your screens to show all the same content, then there is really NO chance at all, to display a content on just one of them. The cloning of the screens is done by the display driver - so: no way!

Comment: Don't do this yourself.  Just use a utility like TightVNC to clone the display.